# Backquote in Arial font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Is there a workaround for the ugly backquote in the Arial font?

For example, running `xelatex` on the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
Here's something ``quoted''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}`

Comment: @egreg: Oops, just saw this after I posted an answer. If you'd like to post, I'll delete mine

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Don't worry: I wouldn't have added that capital final comment. :)

Answer (score 6):

By default, fontspec doesn't activate the standard TeX quote ligatures, Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
Here's something ``quoted''.
\end{document}
```

Of course, some people might say that the 'ugly backquote' isn't the only thing about Arial that's ugly...

Comment: Hey, if you say something is ugly you must recommend something better looking so that we can make the world a better looking place! Any particular sans serif font one ought to use instead of Arial?

Comment: @N.N. Well, if you *insist* on using sans serif for text, then perhaps [Source Sans Pro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcesans.adobe/), though beauty is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: The German typographer [Paul Renner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Renner) did typeset a whole [book about typography](http://www.amazon.com/Die-Kunst-Typographie-Paul-Renner/dp/3875124146/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1346414030&sr=8-1&keywords=Die+Kunst+der+Typographie) in his own sans serif [Futura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_%28typeface%29) which doesn't look bad at all (though a bit too geometric for my taste).

Comment: @cgnieder It really is a matter (mostly) of personal taste. My own feeling is that I've never seen a book set in sans-serif, however marvellous, that I haven't wondered 'I bet that would be *even better* in serif'

Comment: I admit my own feeling is very similar. However, it suits Paul Renner's book really well. But I guess he would do it differently nowadays. The book is from 1939 and he was certainly influenced by the [Bauhaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauhaus) at the time.

Comment: Precisely what I needed. Thanks! For the record, I'm not using Arial by choice but if you've got to use it, it may as well look as good as it can :)